# Possessive “de” with partitive “de”

Tags: articles

I understand that you can often translate the English *some* with the French partitive *de* like so:

> I met some vegetarians → J’ai rencontré des végétariens.

If I instead said:

> J’ai rencontré les végétariens

I assume that would have a different meaning, maybe that I met all of the vegetarians within some particular context.

How do I distinguish between these two if I add *de* for another reason, such as to mark the possessive? For example, how do I translate this:

> I read a book from some vegetarians.

It seems like this could maybe need two *de*’s like this:

> J’ai lu un livre de des végétariens.

However this sounds very odd to me. If I changed it to just *un livre des végétariens*, would that be indistinguishable from the book belonging to *les végétariens*? Is there a better way to say this?

Answer (score 5):

> *J'ai rencontré les végétariens*

means "I met **the** vegetarians".

> *J'ai lu un livre <s>de des</s> végétariens*

is not grammatical. You might say:

> *J'ai lu un livre de végétariens*

but it is ambiguous, it might mean as well "I read a book about vegetarians."
As you suspected:

> *J'ai lu un livre des végétariens*

is also ambiguous and can mean "a book belonging to..."

To make clear the book was written by some vegetarians, you might say:

> *J'ai lu un livre écrit par des végétariens.*

Comment: Definitely, the last one is the best, "j'ai lu un livre de végétarien" sounds really weird to me tho, if you want to say "suitable for vegetarians" I would use "j'ai lu un livre pour végétariens" or even better "j'ai lu un livre à l'intention des végétariens"

Comment: @Flying_whale You are right, after thinking about it, I agree *suitable for* was too far fetched. Removed. Thanks!